# How to make border-image work correctly on Safari?

Tags: css, ios, macos, safari

I am trying to add an image as a border, so I used the border-image CSS property. It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. I researched it on StackOverflow and other sites and tried the code they wrote but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
.border-around-style {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    -moz-border-image: url("assets/img/site-images/home/border.png") 500 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url("assets/img/site-images/home/border.png") 500 round;
    -o-border-image: url("assets/img/site-images/home/border.png") 500 round;
    border-image: url("assets/img/site-images/home/border.png") 500 fill round;
 }
```

This is how it looks like in Chrome
[image]

This is how it looks like in Safari
[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? or how to achieve the results using any other method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is not because of safari. its because a iphone has a different width and height than for instance a laptop. if you want the same result on every device you should use media-queries. w3schools explains it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Comment: it is not working even on the mac laptop. So, it's not related with responsiveness.

Comment: what do you mean its not working on mac laptop? can you show me a example?

Comment: it looks the same as on iPhone. I shared the image on the question. Look at it.